# Can we change Jboss default deploy folder path?

Tags: deployment, jboss

Let's assume I've war file in one location in file system and I have Jboss server installed at different location in file system.Now my question is there any way Jboss can access my war file directly.
In short I don't want to move my war file in deploy folder instead I want location of war file to be treated as deploy folder.

Is it possible??If yes then how?

Comment: Take a look https://developer.jboss.org/thread/202819

Answer (score 2):

Add path of custom deployment directory in `standalone-*xml` like :

> ```
> <paths>
>     <path name="custom.dir" path="/PATH_TO/jboss/applications"/>
> </paths>
> ```

and then in `deployment-scanner` subsystem mention it like :

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
   <deployment-scanner path="customDeployDir" relative-to="custom.dir" > scan-interval="5000"/>
   </subsystem>
```